# Scrollbar Functionality in Typescript in angular 7

Tags: angular7

I have 10 items .I am selecting 4th item .On selection of item i am displaying confirmation  popup .On click of Ok in popup it navigates to another page.In that page I am showing all those 10 items .But my concern is whatever the item i am selecting the scrollbar should comes to that particular item.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. In order to increase the quality of your question you should consider adding more details and some code. This will help a lot when trying to answer your question.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]